# Animate Canvas using for loop and setInterval

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to animate canvas using for loop and setInterval, but no luck so far... Here's what I have in my code:

```
//loop function
function loop(){
    var dynamic = 0;
    var v = 10;
    var x, y;

    for (dynamic = 0; dynamic < v; dynamic++) {
        x = dynamic * 1;
        y = dynamic * 1;
        c.clearRect(0, 0, 350, 350);
        c.fillStyle = '#87CEEB';
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        c.fill();
    }
}

setInterval(loop, 20);
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You're running through the entire animation loop every time `loop()` executes. All you'll see is the last frame of the animation. You need to execute the body of the loop only once each time the `setInterval()` timer fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before: move your dynamic out of the animation loop and change dynamic inside the loop.

A summary of animation is this:

1. Set your starting variables (like dynamic) *outside* your  for loop
2. Inside the animation loop() you want to animate the canvas by 1 move (not many moves), like this:

   ```
     + Increment your dynamic variable to induce motion.

     + Set your x & y to reflect the changes to dynamic.

     + Clear the canvas to prepare for this animation frame

     + Draw stuff!
   ```
3. After the loop, start the animation with setInterval()
4. If you animation runs off the screen, you might as well turn it off!

Here is some code and a Fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fFfRS/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var c=canvas.getContext("2d");

        // set the dynamic outside the loop
        var dynamic = 10;
        var x;
        var y;

         //loop function
        function loop(){

            // change dynamic
           dynamic=dynamic*1.1;
           x = dynamic;
           y = dynamic*1.2;

            // stop the the animation if it runs out-of-canvas
            if (x>canvas.width || y>canvas.height){
                c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                clearInterval(myTimer);
                alert("animation done!");
            }

           // clear the canvas for this loop's animation
           c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
           c.fillStyle = '#87CEEB';

           // draw
           c.beginPath();
           c.arc(x,y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
           c.fill();
        }
        var myTimer=setInterval(loop,20);       

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should move the `dynamic` variable to the outside? You seem to draw the circle at the same point every `loop`.

```
var dynamic = 0;
//loop function
function loop(){
  var v = 10;
  var x, y;
  x = dynamic * 1;
  y = dynamic * 1;
  c.clearRect(0,0, 350,350);
  c.fillStyle = '#87CEEB';
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(x,y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  c.fill();

  ++dynamic;
}

setInterval(loop,20);
```

Comment: Close. Every time `dynamic` hits `v`, it should reset to 0 inside `loop()`.